# Keep Compiler From Removing (Optimizing) Assembly Reference

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, autofac, .net-standard-2.0

We are having some behavior issues using dotnet and autofac.

I have a ViewModel which has a reference to a "ServceClient" (with the namespaces ending in 'Service.Client').  What I'd like to do, is in my Startup.cs load all assembly references ending in 'Service.Client' and using Autofac to scan and load models from that assembly.  We have noticed that doing this will not load the assemblies as expected.

```
var assemblies = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()
    .Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Service.Client")
    .Select(x => Assembly.Load(x)).ToList();
```

What we've had to do is in the Startup.cs have a list of types such as

```
var ref = new ArrayList() { typeof(..Servce.Client) }
```

By doing that, the referenced assembly is not in the `.GetReferencedAssemblies()`.

My question is, how can I either tell the compiler that this assembly is referenced and used by DI, so do not optimize it out?  It is a big pain to have to make sure we have a 'fake' reference in our startup.

Edited to specify: ASP.net NetCore 2.0 - MVC app targeting netcoreapp2.0 and the libraries we are referencing are targeting netstandard2.0

Comment: Might be good to explain what kind of app it is. Answer could differ based on app type.

Comment: Sorry, this is a net core app 2.0 (web Mac)

Comment: So, very specifically, ASP.NET Core 2 0 targeting... netstandard2.0? (It'd be good to update the question, with the info, too.)

Comment: It's been updated. Thanks

Comment: Have you considered adding some code hacks to force references like `GC.KeepAlive(new SomethingFromTheAssembly())` or just copying the assemblies into place in a post-build step?

Comment: That is what we are having to do.  It's a pain because I now have a growing list of 15-20 'references' in a list